# Sumarizing data depending on time and date

Tags: r, date, split, summary

I have a workspace where I have study of the weather of every hour past one year (temperature, CO2 and stuff).
What I need to do is split whole workspace depending on date (cause I have several 2009-01-01 etc) and in next step summarize the data for each day separetly (I'm looking for summary of every variable for every day separetly).

I was searching for some kind of function and have one, which is almoust good. Separating day works quite good, but summary is really bad.

```
df <- data.frame(date=rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2009-01-01"), by="day", length.out=31), each=1))
summary(split(df, as.Date(df$date),AM19))
```

Comment: Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Comment: The thing is, this function summarize only the date not all of my variables.